# Git merge local history to remote repository

Tags: git, merge, commit

I have restructured my project folders. I see that i lost commit history before restructuring of files in my remote repository.

I have the history before restructuring locally. 
Right now everyone who clone the repository doesn't have the commit history before restructuring. 
Is there anyway i can rebuild the commit history and merge it to the remote repository?

When i try this command :

```
git log --follow pom.xml
```

I can see full history of file, but when i dont use --follow the log stops at restructuring commit.I would like that it shows all the history. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? "I see that i lost history" where do you see it ? "I have the history before restructuring" again, where ? There's no reason per se to lose your repo history when you move some directories inside your project, so it seems you're omitting to mention something.

Comment: Sorry i try to describe more specific. When i select a file i intellij and click on show history i see the full commit history of the selected file. When i do the same in bitbucket on the same file i only see the history from the day i restructured the project.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to lose history in Git is to remove commits.  This is because the commits *are* the history.  There is no file history; there are only commits.

When you use `git log --follow pom.xml`, you are telling Git to *synthesize* a file history, by wandering through the commit history and noting when a file named `pom.xml` is touched.  The `--follow` option tells Git that in addition to checking to see if `pom.xml` is *changed* in that commit, it should also check to see if it is *renamed* in that commit.  If so, Git checks *earlier* commits for the *old name* (including its full directory path) instead of the new name—so Git is no longer looking for `new/pom.xml` but now looking for `old/pom.xml` or whatever, and constructing a file history for *that* file.

If you use an IDE, the IDE must do the same thing as Git—synthesize a file history by selecting commits that change that file, and check for rename operations in the process, if that's what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found out thats an issue only on Bitbucket and Eclipse. 
Bitbucket shows all commits to the repository but can not show the sinbgle file log with the command --follow.
The same issue is with Eclipse.
Intellij works fine.